# In reference to a specific event, does "since" exclude the event occuring in the meantime?

Tags: sentence

> It's been 43 days since I've closed this door.

Above statement clearly implies that the person in question hasn't closed the door for over a month. However, I feel like technically you would have to say "It's been 43 days since I've *last* closed this door" to truly say that you haven't closed the dear at all in the meantime.

The reason I think you might need to specify, is because it seems to me like the example sentence might refer to an arbitrary occurrence of the door being closed, as opposed to the door closing in general.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Your sample sentence wouldn't make much sense if you didn't mean the _last_ time you closed the door.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a peeve

Comment: It's unlikely to be 43 days exactly, no matter what phraseology one chooses. In this example, 'six weeks' is a more likely approximation, but if an 'exact' time interval is needed, 'It's been exactly 43 days, 2 hours, 6 minutes and 11 ... no, 12 ... no, 13 ...seconds since I last closed ...'. No actual time is given truly exactly.

Comment: Your use of the present perfect ("I've closed" = I *have closed*) suggests that the closure continues to the present.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm assuming there is some kind of rule against posting things which are a pet peeve of someone? That's not the case, here. This is a genuine question that popped up between me and a colleague, neither of us thought about it before. Also, English is our second language.

Comment: @Lawrence I agree, it does suggest that. I guess I was just wondering if there was a case to be made for the argument that it could, in fact, also mean that it's simply referring to a singular occurrence on which the door was closed. It's pretty misleading to interpret it like that, I guess I have my answer.

Comment: @Patriot There's a little more to it. I'm preparing an answer.

Comment: @Patriot: I don't know about any explicit "rule" against "peeves". I just think that given how often people say things like ***Hello there! I haven't seen you since last year!***, it's nit-picking in the extreme to fret about whether it's "correct" to exclude the ***current*** situation from references involving ***since***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I see, it wasn't intended to come across as nit-picky. It genuinely was case of us wondering "Given that I closed the door 43 days ago, does the fact that we've opened (and subsequently re-closed) that door in the meantime make it a lie to say that "It's been 43 days since I've closed that door."

Comment: You yourself say that the sentence 'clearly implies that the person in question hasn't closed the door for over a month'; as a matter of **pragmatics** that's how it would be understood in almost all cases. It is true that its **semantics** does not entirely rule out the possibility of there having been other door closings in the meantime, and that ('technically' as you put it) the word *last* rules out that possibility, but in real life the pragmatic implication (implicature) is so strong that this is almost never needed. Given that you seem to already know all that, what is the question?

Comment: That's three times you've used ***in the meantime***, where what I ***assume*** you mean is ***at*** (or ***immediately before***) ***time of utterance***. Note that "immediately before" may vary in scope depending on the context, so *It's been 43 **days** since I've closed that door* might still be natural several ***hours*** after opening it for the second time in 43 days, but it wouldn't normally work if the most recent repetition was ***yesterday*** or earlier.

Comment: @jsw29 I recognized the implication, I wasn't sure of how strong it was.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your assumption is correct. I hadn't considered that it might vary based on the elapsed time between openings and the stated time it had been since opening.

Comment: *I met John **last week**. I haven't seen him since we were at school together back in the 70s.* Works fine for me.

Comment: @Patriot, the implication is very strong, unless there is something in the context that weakens it. For example, if the preceding sentences were all about some act of door closing that had great significance, the sentence (without *last*) would be understood to be about the time that has elapsed since **that** act, even if it wasn't the most recent act of one's closing the door.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "since" doesn't (simplistically) constrain the action's continuation or otherwise. Consider the following:

1. It hasn't rained since yesterday.
2. The window shuts since the handyman fixed it.

With (1), the present perfect "*has (not) rained*" suggests that the closure continues to the present. Your example is similar.

With (2), although it could be argued that the simple present allows for the window to close *and* open since it was fixed, what's really happening is that *shuts* references an 'ability' or capability rather than a (static) state. The window's ability to shut continues to the present.

The word "since" does indicate that something continues uninterrupted between the specified time and the present, but that something isn't always 'just' the action or state one might pick out syntactically from the sentence.

In your *door* example, though, the natural reading would be that it's the (simple) state of the door that "since" holds closed through to the present.

Comment: @jsw29 I've changed my example to reference a window instead of a door.